# Pass params to $http into directive

Tags: angularjs

I use this model of service to get commencts from DB:

```
.service('getComArt', function($http) {
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    this.getData = function(callbackFunc) {
        $http.get('http://www.domain.it/commenct.php')
            .success(function(data) {
                callbackFunc(data)
            })
            .error(function() {
                alert("Error!")
            })
    }
})
```

Is it possible call the service adding a param taken by controller?
For example If I would use the same service, but extracting only hte comment with id = xxxx!

Comment: you can add an additional parameter to the `getData` function, however, you'd have to modify your php script to handle retrieving a single row by id

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get by passing parameters, all you have to do is concatenate to the URL, otherwise if your method is POST, you must define the data

Get:

```
$http.get('http://www.domain.it/commenct.php/data1/data2')
```

Post :

```
var data = {name:'John', password : '1234'}
$http.post('http://www.domain.it/commenct.php/', data).success(successCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think explain me bad! So this is the solution:

Create a factory to make the $http call

```
.factory('getContent', function($http) {
    return function(id){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://www.domain.it/page.php',
            params: {id:id}
         });
    }
})
```

Then in the controller:

```
getContent(id).success(
    function (data) {$scope.items = data}
);
```